# Why Storage-Class Specifiers are used to determine two independent properties?

Tags: c, static, storage, linkage

From [Storage-class specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration):

> The storage-class specifiers determine two independent properties of the names they declare: storage duration and linkage.

So, for example, when `static` keyword is used on global variables and functions (who's storage class is static anyway) it sets their linkage to Internal-linkage. When used on variables inside functions (which have no linkage) - it sets their storage class to static.

My question is: why is the same specifier used for both things?

Comment: Likely because the two independent properties rarely need to be independently used.  In the end, it is asking why C was done this way. - I suspect for simplicity and it matched the art of the time.

Comment: @chux, Can you elaborate? I don't understand why "the two independent properties rarely need to be independently used.". I don't understand the relation between static storage and internal linkage and why the two are tightly bound..

Comment: Hopefully the below answer(s) will suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is mostly historical: linkage came into the design of C language as an afterthought. In the early versions you could redeclare global variables as many times as you wish, and linker would merge all these declarations for you:

> Ritchie's original intention had been to model C's rules on FORTRAN COMMON declarations, on the theory that any machine that could handle FORTRAN would be ready for C. In the common-block model, a public variable may be declared multiple times; identical declarations are merged by the linker. ([source](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/c_evolution.html))

The current rule of a single declaration came later, along with `extern` keyword. At that point there was a body of C code significant enough to make backward compatibility important. That is probably the reason why language designers refrained from introducing a new keyword for handling linkage, reusing `static` instead.

Comment: Ah the `COMMON` statement - shuddder.